# Using JsonConvert.SerializeObject with a class : ObservableObject and property attribute ObservableProperty do not serialize as expected

Tags: maui

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

I'm using this command:
`var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serie);`

to serialise following class:

```cs
public partial class Serie : ObservableObject
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    [ObservableProperty]
    long id;

    [JsonProperty("series")]
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(SeriesAndSubSeries))]
    string title;
    
    [JsonProperty("sub_series")]
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(SeriesAndSubSeries))]
    string subSerie;
}
```

and I get this result:

```json
{"id":702,"series":"Androïden","sub_series":"","Id":702,"Title":"Androïden","SubSerie":""}
```

I am expecting only this:

```json
{"id":702,"series":"Androïden","sub_series":""}
```

It looks like all source generated fields are also added to json.
Can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a conflict when you use both `[JsonProperty()]` and `[ObservableProperty]`. So you can try to just use the `[JsonProperty()]`. You can try the following code and it has the result you want.

```
      public partial class Serie : ObservableObject
      {
            
            long id;
            [JsonProperty("id")] // this attribute needs to be added above the Id not id
            public long Id { get => id; set => SetProperty(ref id, value); }
            // this line has the same effect as the [ObservableProperty]
            
            string title;
            [JsonProperty("series")]
            public string Title { get => title; set => SetProperty(ref title, value); }
            
            string subSerie;
            [JsonProperty("sub_series")]
            public string SubSerie { get => subSerie; set => SetProperty(ref subSerie, value); }

      }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what I had before, so i'm reverting back to it. And it still works. I was trying to improve the code with the latest improvements from the Maui Community Toolkit.  But sometimes it's alright to stick to proven functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this to make use of attribute forwarding of `ObservableProperty`:

```cs
public partial class Serie : ObservableObject
{
    [property: JsonPropertyName("id")]
    [ObservableProperty]
    long id;

    [property: JsonPropertyName("series")]
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(SeriesAndSubSeries))]
    string title;
    
    [property: JsonPropertyName("sub_series")]
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(SeriesAndSubSeries))]
    string subSerie;
}
```

If doing so, the attributes are applied to the code generated properties `Id`, `Title` and `SubSerie` instead of the private fields `id`, `title` and `subSerie`.

For more information, see the corrseponding github [issue](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/413) and [pull request](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/pull/449)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it works and retains the less verbose code style provided by the MVVM toolkit